# Duplcated whois output

Tags: server, 19.04, whois

I seem to be having an issue with whois it appears to be duplicating the output, this is unfortunately interfering with one of my scripts.

I have tested this both on my personal laptop as well as my Ubuntu server, I have also tested this on a fresh install of Ubuntu as well.

This is not an issue on my CentOs7 servers. I have however not tested this on a different distribution.

My knowledge of ubuntu us not that much in comparison to CentOs however I don't believe there would be that large of a difference between these utilities.

Here's a sample of what it looks like when I run a `whois`:

```
╔═══[Date: Sat Apr 27 Time: 05:04 AM]═[arctic@Sevastopol.foxdale.net]
╠══[Total Commands: 977]═[Issued Commands: 4]=[Logins: 2]
╠═[~]
╚[λ]-[$]>-➤ whois foxdale.net
   Domain Name: FOXDALE.NET
   Registry Domain ID: 1830382905_DOMAIN_NET-VRSN
   Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.namecheap.com
   Registrar URL: http://www.namecheap.com
   Updated Date: 2018-09-08T06:15:03Z
   Creation Date: 2013-10-08T18:25:51Z
   Registry Expiry Date: 2019-10-08T18:25:51Z
   Registrar: NameCheap, Inc.
   Registrar IANA ID: 1068
   Registrar Abuse Contact Email: abuse@namecheap.com
   Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1.6613102107
   Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
   Name Server: NS1.FOXDALE.NET
   Name Server: NS2.FOXDALE.NET
   DNSSEC: unsigned
   URL of the ICANN Whois Inaccuracy Complaint Form: https://www.icann.org/wicf/
>>> Last update of whois database: 2019-04-27T10:37:41Z <<<

For more information on Whois status codes, please visit https://icann.org/epp

NOTICE: The expiration date displayed in this record is the date the
registrar's sponsorship of the domain name registration in the registry is
currently set to expire. This date does not necessarily reflect the expiration
date of the domain name registrant's agreement with the sponsoring
registrar.  Users may consult the sponsoring registrar's Whois database to
view the registrar's reported date of expiration for this registration.

TERMS OF USE: You are not authorized to access or query our Whois
database through the use of electronic processes that are high-volume and
automated except as reasonably necessary to register domain names or
modify existing registrations; the Data in VeriSign Global Registry
Services' ("VeriSign") Whois database is provided by VeriSign for
information purposes only, and to assist persons in obtaining information
about or related to a domain name registration record. VeriSign does not
guarantee its accuracy. By submitting a Whois query, you agree to abide
by the following terms of use: You agree that you may use this Data only
for lawful purposes and that under no circumstances will you use this Data
to: (1) allow, enable, or otherwise support the transmission of mass
unsolicited, commercial advertising or solicitations via e-mail, telephone,
or facsimile; or (2) enable high volume, automated, electronic processes
that apply to VeriSign (or its computer systems). The compilation,
repackaging, dissemination or other use of this Data is expressly
prohibited without the prior written consent of VeriSign. You agree not to
use electronic processes that are automated and high-volume to access or
query the Whois database except as reasonably necessary to register
domain names or modify existing registrations. VeriSign reserves the right
to restrict your access to the Whois database in its sole discretion to ensure
operational stability.  VeriSign may restrict or terminate your access to the
Whois database for failure to abide by these terms of use. VeriSign
reserves the right to modify these terms at any time.

The Registry database contains ONLY .COM, .NET, .EDU domains and
Registrars.
Domain name: foxdale.net
Registry Domain ID: 1830382905_DOMAIN_NET-VRSN
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.namecheap.com
Registrar URL: http://www.namecheap.com
Updated Date: 2018-09-08T06:15:03.74Z
Creation Date: 2013-10-08T18:25:51.00Z
Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 2019-10-08T18:25:51.00Z
Registrar: NAMECHEAP INC
Registrar IANA ID: 1068
Registrar Abuse Contact Email: abuse@namecheap.com
Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1.6613102107
Reseller: NAMECHEAP INC
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
Registry Registrant ID:
Registrant Name: WhoisGuard Protected
Registrant Organization:
Registrant Street: P.O. Box 0823-03411
Registrant City: Panama
Registrant State/Province: Panama
Registrant Postal Code:
Registrant Country: PA
Registrant Phone: +507.8365503
Registrant Phone Ext:
Registrant Fax: +51.17057182
Registrant Fax Ext:
Registrant Email: f7a93f5d87af478f876ff6f51b592cb0.protect@whoisguard.com
Registry Admin ID:
Admin Name: WhoisGuard Protected
Admin Organization:
Admin Street: P.O. Box 0823-03411
Admin City: Panama
Admin State/Province: Panama
Admin Postal Code:
Admin Country: PA
Admin Phone: +507.8365503
Admin Phone Ext:
Admin Fax: +51.17057182
Admin Fax Ext:
Admin Email: f7a93f5d87af478f876ff6f51b592cb0.protect@whoisguard.com
Registry Tech ID:
Tech Name: WhoisGuard Protected
Tech Organization:
Tech Street: P.O. Box 0823-03411
Tech City: Panama
Tech State/Province: Panama
Tech Postal Code:
Tech Country: PA
Tech Phone: +507.8365503
Tech Phone Ext:
Tech Fax: +51.17057182
Tech Fax Ext:
Tech Email: f7a93f5d87af478f876ff6f51b592cb0.protect@whoisguard.com
Name Server: ns1.foxdale.net
Name Server: ns2.foxdale.net
DNSSEC: unsigned
URL of the ICANN WHOIS Data Problem Reporting System: http://wdprs.internic.net/
>>> Last update of WHOIS database: 2019-04-27T03:17:32.93Z <<<

!highlight!For more information on Whois status codes, please visit https://icann.org/epp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran this command on both my Ubuntu 18.04 machine and a CentOS 7 VM targeting google.com and the outputs were not identical, but I did not experience any issues with duplication. Rather, it appears the Ubuntu instance was performing two queries: first in all uppercase, then in all lowercase. The timestamps also indicate that these were two separate queries. I suggest adding a pipe to your script like so:

`whois foxdale.net | tail -n 60`

Since the CentOS output is only 60 lines and the first 60 lines or so seem to be identical, you should be able to use this in order to format the output into something useable. You also would be able to reuse the script on your CentOS machines without modification.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this behavior on my Arch machine, with `whois` version 5.4.2. It looks like the developers of `whois` have decided it is useful to query both upper and lowercase domain names. I don't understand why, the Domain Name  implementation specification (RFC 1035) [states that](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-2.3.3) (emphasis mine):

> 2.3.3. Character Case
>
> For all parts of the DNS that are part of the official protocol, **all
> comparisons between character strings (e.g., labels, domain names,
> etc.) are done in a case-insensitive manner**.  At present, this rule is
> in force throughout the domain system without exception.  However,
> future additions beyond current usage may need to use the full binary
> octet capabilities in names, so attempts to store domain names in
> 7-bit ASCII or use of special bytes to terminate labels, etc., should
> be avoided.
>
> When data enters the domain system, its original case should be
> preserved whenever possible.  In certain circumstances this cannot be
> done.  For example, if two RRs are stored in a database, one at x.y
> and one at X.Y, they are actually stored at the same place in the
> database, and hence only one casing would be preserved.  The basic
> rule is that case can be discarded only when data is used to define
> structure in a database, and two names are identical when compared in
> a case insensitive manner.

Given the above, the decision of the `whois` developers seems very strange, but I'm no networking expert so they probably know something I don't.

Presumably, your CentOS has an older version of `whois` which didn't have this behavior. CentOS is not a cutting edge distribution, and usually lags behind other distros which ship new versions of tools more often. Since I can reproduce this on my Arch system, it does seem like this is an upstream decision made by the `whois` devs, and not an issue with Ubuntu.

For what it's worth, this seems to have been added to whois v5.2.17, at least, that was the first version I found in the github repository https://github.com/rfc1036/whois which displayed this behavior.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth explanation of why this behavior is occurring, I didn't even think of comparing the versions, I wish they made a flag to disable this ability :(